# Overriding iOS Storyboard Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

How can you alter constraints that are set in the Storyboard?

I am trying to mimic the Twitter iOS profile page where the header shrinks as you scroll down.

I have a UIScrollView that takes up the entire view.  I then have a UITableView within the UIScrollView.  Within the storyboard I must set a fixed height for the UITableView.  So is has the constraint of Equals Height = 350.

I then try to change the height of it programmatically:

```
 tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height - 30)
```

When I do this it doesn't affect the size of the UITableView at all.  I'm assuming this is because of the storyboard constraints.

Am I missing something or do I need to do this programmatically to start with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't fight against the constraint set in the Storyboard.  Instead, you can create an `@IBOutlet` to the height constraint by finding it in the *Document Outline* view and <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the constraint to your code.  Give it a name like `tableHeightContraint`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, when you want to change the height of the `UITableView`, modify the `constant` property of the constraint:

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.frame.height - 30
```

As @BlackRider noted in the comments, sometimes it is necessary to trigger a layout after constraints have been changed.

Calling:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

will tell Auto Layout to do the apply the constraint if needed.  This is especially true if you are animating the change.  In that case, the `layoutIfNeeded()` call is made inside of the animation block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Good answer. In addition, sometimes it is necessary to force a layout after you change a constraint. E.g.: `view.layoutIfNeeded()`. This is especially important if you're animating a constraint change. In this case `layoutIfNeeded` needs to be called in the animation block.